# Conversion of values in particular fields in UNIX

Tags: unix, sed, gsub

Following values are present in a file

```
A|0001|.00|xyz|.00 
B|0002|1.00|xyz|.00 
C|0003|12.43|xyz|.00
```

I want the values in output file as

```
A|0001|0.00|xyz|0.00 
B|0002|1.00|xyz|0.00 
C|0003|12.43|xyz|0.00
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to normalize numbers in those columns to always have whole part and two significant digits this should do what you want:

```
awk -v FS=\| -v OFS=\| '{$3=sprintf("%.2f", $3); $5=sprintf("%.2f", $5)}7' file

$ cat file
A|0001|.00|xyz|.00
B|0002|1.00|xyz|.00
C|0003|12.43|xyz|.00
D|0004|.54|xyz|1

$ awk -v FS=\| -v OFS=\| '{$3=sprintf("%.2f", $3); $5=sprintf("%.2f", $5)}7' file
A|0001|0.00|xyz|0.00
B|0002|1.00|xyz|0.00
C|0003|12.43|xyz|0.00
D|0004|0.54|xyz|1.00
```

Comment: Thanks Etan. This helps in converting values in specific columns.

Answer (score 2):

Through perl,

```
$ perl -pe 's/\B(?=\.)/0/g' file
A|0001|0.00|xyz|0.00 
B|0002|1.00|xyz|0.00 
C|0003|12.43|xyz|0.00
```

Through sed,

```
$ sed -r 's/\|\./|0./g' file
A|0001|0.00|xyz|0.00 
B|0002|1.00|xyz|0.00 
C|0003|12.43|xyz|0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `awk`

```
awk -F\| '$3~/^\./ {$3="0"$3} $5~/^\./ {$5="0"$5}1' OFS=\| file
A|0001|0.00|xyz|0.00
B|0002|1.00|xyz|0.00
C|0003|12.43|xyz|0.00
```